# Composing Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, extension-methods, iqueryable

I have a method that returns an

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

When I use this as a predicate in a where clause in EF this works fine, until I try to add more items to the predicate with Expression.Or() I run into the following exception:

> The parameter 'xxx' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

Is there some way around this? What causes this exactly?

**SOLVED**

using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In EF, if you call

```
IQueryable<T> query = ...
query.Where( predicate 1 ).Where( predicate 2 )...
```

Then EF will join the `where` clauses with an `AND`

The only way in EF to do an `OR` is to put the predicates in a single call to `IQueryable.Where`

```
IQueryable<T> query = ...
query.Where( predicate 1 || predicate 2 )...
```

Answer (score 2):

To compose OR like AND you can use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

To compose predicates in OR relation, you can do:

```
predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(predicate.Body, newPredicate.Body), newPredicate.Parameters);
```

Comment: Just checked your solution link, what I suggested was identical to that solution, except without the ParameterRebinder feature.

Comment: My solution works if the two predicates have the same parameter. i.e. predicate = p => p.Age >= 18; newPredicate = p => p.Gender = Gender.Male; predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(predicate.Body, newPredicate.Body), newPredicate.Parameters);